# Powershell, web services and object types

Tags: web-services, powershell, reporting-services

I'm new to using `web services` under `powershell`, so maybe I have a basic misunderstanding about something. I'm working with Microsoft's `Reporting Services`. Here is a repro script.

```
$computer = "rptdev"
$uri = "http://$($computer)/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx?WSDL"

$reporting = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential -namespace "ReportingWebService"

$dsRef = new-object ReportingWebService.DataSourceReference
$ds = new-object ReportingWebService.DataSource

$dsRef.GetType()
$ds.GetType()
```

If I run that, I get something that looks more or less like this:

```
Name                BaseType
----                --------
DataSourceReference ReportingWebService.DataSourceDefinitionOrReference
DataSource          System.Object
```

So, my question is: Why does DataSource have `System.Object` as a `BaseType` when `DataSourceReference` clearly has a object type that is based on the web object? They were both created from the `ReportingWebService` namespace, weren't they?

My root problem is that I need to hand an array of `DataSources` back to `SetItemDataSources`, and `SetItemDataSources` chokes on an array of `System.Objects`, and I don't seem to be able to *cast* it to what I want.

Answer (score 2):

All this means is that the "DataSource" class inherits directly from System.Object.  Whereas "DataSourceReference" inherits from "DataSourceDefinitionOrReference", then maybe something else, then System.Object.

However, I do not think that is your problem.  Your problem is probably PowerShell's automatic splitting and recombining of collections as generic collections of System.Object.  You can control this by setting a static type on the collection like so (I'm guessing on this API you are using since I haven't used it myself):

```
$computer = "rptdev"
$uri = "http://$($computer)/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx?WSDL"

$reporting = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential -namespace "ReportingWebService"

[ReportingWebService.DataSource[]]$DataSources = <do something to get your data sources>
$reporting.SetItemDataSources($DataSources)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a single object and you want to pass an array of objects (i.e. an array with a single element in it - your sole object), you use the @() syntax:

```
ps> $o = new-object mynamespace.myobj
ps> $thing.Method( @($o) )
```

-Oisin